# Uncaught TypeError: Object app.data.proxy.CustomSql has no method 'apply' sencha touch

Tags: sqlite, proxy, sencha-touch, overriding

Hi Stackoverflow people!

I'm coding in sencha touch framework, and I have define an override to Ext.data.proxy.Sql...

when app load, display me the next error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object App.data.proxy.CustomSql has no method 'apply' ...`

The override is:

```
Ext.define('app.data.proxy.CustomSql', {    
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Sql',
    isSQLProxy: false, 
    setSql: function(sql) {
        this.customSql = sql;
        console.log('definiendo');
    },
    getSql: function() {
        return(this.customSql);
    },
    selectRecords: function(transaction, params, callback, scope) {
        console.log('seles');
        var me = this,
        table = me.getTable(),
        idProperty = me.getModel().getIdProperty(),
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table,
        records = [],
        filterStatement = ' WHERE ',
        sortStatement = ' ORDER BY ',
        i, ln, data, result, count, rows, filter, sorter, property, value;


        result = new Ext.data.ResultSet({
        records: records,
        success: true
    });


    if (!Ext.isObject(params)) {
        sql += filterStatement + idProperty + ' = ' + params;
    } else {
        ln = params.filters && params.filters.length;
        if (ln) {
            for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
                filter = params.filters[i];
                property = filter.getProperty();
                value = filter.getValue();
                if (property !== null) {
                    sql += filterStatement + property + ' ' + (filter.getAnyMatch() ? ('LIKE \'%' + value + '%\'') : ('= \'' + value + '\''));
                    filterStatement = ' AND ';
                }
            }
        }


        ln = params.sorters && params.sorters.length;
        if (ln) {
            for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
                sorter = params.sorters[i];
                property = sorter.getProperty();
                if (property !== null) {
                    sql += sortStatement + property + ' ' + sorter.getDirection();
                    sortStatement = ', ';
                }
            }
        }


        // handle start, limit, sort, filter and group params
        if (params.page !== undefined) {
            sql += ' LIMIT ' + parseInt(params.start, 10) + ', ' + parseInt(params.limit, 10);
        }
    }


    console.log(this.customSql);        
    if (this.customSql) {
        sql = this.customSql;
        delete this.customSql; 
    }


    transaction.executeSql(sql, null,
        function(transaction, resultSet) {
            rows = resultSet.rows;
            count = rows.length;


            for (i = 0, ln = count; i < ln; i++) {
                data = rows.item(i);
                records.push({
                    clientId: null,
                    id: data[idProperty],
                    data: data,
                    node: data
                });
            }


            result.setSuccess(true);
            result.setTotal(count);
            result.setCount(count);


            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback.call(scope || me, result);
            }
        },
        function(transaction, errors) {
            result.setSuccess(false);
            result.setTotal(0);
            result.setCount(0);


            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback.call(scope || me, result);
            }
        }
    );
},

});
```

Any idea?
Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: Just a note: you have a `,` before the last `Ext.define` closing brackets `});`  this can break Sencha

Answer (score 1):

Go through your code:

1. <del>in the **selectRecords() function** you have a lot of `,` instead of `;`:</del>

   ```
   selectRecords: function(transaction, params, callback, scope) {
       console.log('seles');
       var me = this,
       table = me.getTable(),
   ...
   ```

   <del>You are mixing `;` and `,`. 

   It's a **function**, you should always put **`;`** at the end of lines.</del>

   As **@StephenTremaine** kindly pointed out (not sure how did I overlook this) the above is not a porblem, as one can simply use commas resulting in a declaration list.
2. You have a **`,`** before the last Ext.define closing brackets **`});`**

   ```
       },
   });
   ```

   This is wrong.

Tried to clean up and fix your code:

```
Ext.define('app.data.proxy.CustomSql', {
    override: 'Ext.data.proxy.Sql',
    isSQLProxy: false, 
    setSql: function(sql) {
        this.customSql = sql;
        console.log('definiendo');
    },
    getSql: function() {
        return(this.customSql);
    },
    selectRecords: function(transaction, params, callback, scope) {
        console.log('seles');
        var me = this;
        table = me.getTable();
        idProperty = me.getModel().getIdProperty();
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table;
        records = [];
        filterStatement = ' WHERE ';
        sortStatement = ' ORDER BY ';
        i, ln, data, result, count, rows, filter, sorter, property, value;


        result = new Ext.data.ResultSet({
            records: records,
            success: true
        });


        if (!Ext.isObject(params)) {
            sql += filterStatement + idProperty + ' = ' + params;
        } else {
            ln = params.filters && params.filters.length;
            if (ln) {
                for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
                    filter = params.filters[i];
                    property = filter.getProperty();
                    value = filter.getValue();
                    if (property !== null) {
                        sql += filterStatement + property + ' ' + (filter.getAnyMatch() ? ('LIKE \'%' + value + '%\'') : ('= \'' + value + '\''));
                        filterStatement = ' AND ';
                    }
                }
            }

            ln = params.sorters && params.sorters.length;
            if (ln) {
                for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
                    sorter = params.sorters[i];
                    property = sorter.getProperty();
                    if (property !== null) {
                        sql += sortStatement + property + ' ' + sorter.getDirection();
                        sortStatement = ', ';
                    }
                }
            }

            // handle start, limit, sort, filter and group params
            if (params.page !== undefined) {
                sql += ' LIMIT ' + parseInt(params.start, 10) + ', ' + parseInt(params.limit, 10);
            }
        }


        console.log(this.customSql);
        if (this.customSql) {
            sql = this.customSql;
            delete this.customSql; 
        }


        transaction.executeSql(sql, null,
            function(transaction, resultSet) {
                rows = resultSet.rows;
                count = rows.length;


                for (i = 0, ln = count; i < ln; i++) {
                    data = rows.item(i);
                    records.push({
                        clientId: null,
                        id: data[idProperty],
                        data: data,
                        node: data
                    });
                }

                result.setSuccess(true);
                result.setTotal(count);
                result.setCount(count);

                if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback.call(scope || me, result);
                }
            },

            function(transaction, errors) {
                result.setSuccess(false);
                result.setTotal(0);
                result.setCount(0);

                if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback.call(scope || me, result);
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I think all the "extra" commas after the var are a good idea.  It's just a declaration/initialization list.  No different than something like "var test = 1, tester = 2, other = 3;"  When you add the semicolons, you declare all the rest of the variables in the global scope which can be bad.  That last comma before the close of the define block is definitely a problem though.  Good catch there.

Comment: @StephenTremaine you are absolutely right. Not sure why I thought the other way.